# Finding distinct set of columns in two tables?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, distinct, union

Using SQLite, let's say I have these two tables:

```
A
_id  num  name  group  data1  data2   
1    4    ABC   I              
2    4    CDE   I              
3    5    CDE   I                       
4    5    CDE   I                       
5    5    CDE   II             

B (doesn't have a _id column)
     num  name  group  data1  data2 
     4    ABC   I      x      y     
     4    CDE   I      x1     y1    
     5    CDE   I      x2     y2    
     5    CDE   I      x3     y3    
     5    CDE   II     x4     y4    
     6    DEF   III    x5     y5
```

Note that I have no primary key in Table B. I want to update the values in Table A with the data values from Table B, but only for the rows that can be uniquely identified by columns `num`, `name` and `group` in both tables or that do not exist at all in Table A. These columns are essentially a sort of combined key, and the only way to connect two rows in the database.

The result would look something like this:

```
A
_id  num  name  group  data1  data2   
1    4    ABC   I      x      y 
2    4    CDE   I      x1     y1
3    5    CDE   I               
4    5    CDE   I               
5    5    CDE   II     x4     y4
6    6    DEF   III    x5     y5
```

I have been trying to wrap my head around this for a few days and tried various solutions, but none that seem any good. My actual tables contain about 3000 rows each (Table B is an update of Table A with a few hundred minor changes). I have come to the conclusion that there will need to be some manual edits for rows that are not easily uniquely identified, but it would be nice to minimize them as much as possible. Most rows seem to have unique combinations of `num`, `name` and `group`, so that's my aim at the moment.

I had an idea about selecting all distinct (with regards to `num`, `name` and `group`) rows from Table A and all similarly distinct rows from Table B, and then I should be able to just iterate over the rows from B, find the corresponding (again with regards to columns `num`, `name` and `group`) rows in Table A and copy the values from B to A.

But I'm not sure that's the way to do it, or how to go about it...

Comment: You could `LEFT JOIN TableA` and find what combinations of `num`, `name` and `group` won't get matching _id in TableA and need manual input. I don't see what is the problem updating those that match, you just do `inner join`? Maybe SQLite doesn't support `UPDATE [..] FROM`, so you just need to make loop in some programming language that will execute ~3000 updates.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński The problem is I can only update those that have a distinct combination of  `num`, `name` and `group` in both tables. I'm not sure how to do that with an `INNER JOIN`? Don't I need to use `DISTINCT` somewhere?

Comment: Both tables can have more than 1 row for given set of `num, name, group`?

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Yes, as shown in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns only unique `B` rows

```
select num, name, group, min(data1) as data1, min(data2) as data2 
from B
group by num, name, group
having count(*)=1
```

Use it to update `A` table.

Answer (score 0):

At first update existing unique rows:

```
with q(_id,data1,data2) as(
  select A._id,B.data1,B.data2
    from A
    join B
      on B.num=A.num and B.name=A.name and B."group"=A."group"
   group by A.num,A.name,A."group"
   having count(1)=1
)
update A
   set data1=(select data1 from Q where Q._id=A._id),
       data2=(select data1 from Q where Q._id=A._id)
 where A._id in(select _id from Q);
```

Then insert new rows:

```
insert into A(num,name,"group",data1,data2)
 select num,name,"group",data1,data2
   from B
  where not exists(select 1
                     from A
                    where B.num=A.num and B.name=A.name and B."group"=A."group"
                   );
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a start :) One of the many things that further complicates the matter is that the columns in the combined key `num`, `name` and `group` could also have been changed in Table B, so simply adding everything that doesn't exist won't work. But I think that's where manual labour becomes necessary (Although one solution I considered was to check if only either `num`, `name` or `group` is distinct in case where the combination can not be found in Table A, and use that as the key instead. But I think it would not save me any time to implement...)

Comment: And then there is of course the problem that not all rows have a unique combination of `num`, `name` and `group`... sigh...